# My If statement is not working in Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, middleware

I am trying to make a middleware which can filter my http request by checking if the **"$created_by"** that I am passing through the request alreday exists in my **"users"** table 
If it does I want to proceed with my **"$next($request)"** 
And if it doesn't I wanna redirect it.

When the situation is this:-

```
if ($ip->uuid == $request->created_by)
```

It redirects to **$next($request);** which is correct 
But when the **"$request->created_by"** is not present in **DB** it which makes $ip null 
And it shows this error **"Trying to get property 'uuid' of non-object"**

**Here's my Middleware:-**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class Posts
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)

     {
      $ip = DB::table('users')->where('uuid', '=', $request->created_by)->first();
        // dd($ip);
       if ($ip->uuid == $request->created_by) {
        if ($ip == null) {
             return redirect('https://www.google.com');
        }


       }

        return $next($request);

        }
    }
```

Comment: If not in DB, then $ip is null. You can't check for $ip->uuid at that point in your first if. That property is not present, as the variable is null.

Comment: You have to make sure $ip is not null before trying to access property uuid.

Comment: yess ik the value is null that's what i want "if the value is null i want it to redirect it to google.com"

Comment: It is too bad you were not inspired to try something yourself after many people had directed you to were the error originated from. You are not learning much from working this way.

Comment: I knew the $ip is null but i didn't knew much ways to solve such problem  *-I'll do better next time*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use optional to prevent error if you object is null.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    $ip = DB::table('users')->where('uuid', '=', $request->created_by)->first();
    if(optional($ip)->uuid == $request->created_by) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('https://www.google.com');

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, would you mind helping me with another question?

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

You already made the comparison in DB, update `handle()` to be:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
       $ip = DB::table('users')->where('uuid', '=', $request->created_by)->first();

       if (is_object($ip) {

         return $next($request);

       }

       return redirect('https://www.google.com');
    }
```

Comment: even if the value is null its still executing **$next($request)**

Comment: Thanks for the help, would you mind helping me with another question

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that $ip is not null before trying to access property uuid.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    $ip = DB::table('users')->where('uuid', '=', $request->created_by)->first();
    if(is_null($ip) || $ip->uuid !== $request->created_by) {
        return redirect('https://www.google.com');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Thaanks for the help, would you mind helping me with another question?